# Ansible: Synchronize from local machine to all other machines in a group

Tags: ssh, ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to transfer a root owned folder on my local machine to root owned folders on all other machines in a group called 'group'.

When I run the playbook it hangs, which makes me think that it might be an ssh issue. However, I can ssh to the remote machines without a password through the command line as user 'me'.

I have the following but I believe it tries to copy from the remote machine to the same remote machine. But I don't think ansible even makes it this far so I think I have two issues to fix.

```
  synchronize:
    src: /root/owned/dir/
    dest: /root/owned/dir/
  delegate_to: "{{ hostvars[item].ip_address }}"
  with_items: "{{ groups['group'] }}"
  when: inventory_hostname != "{{item}}"
  become: yes
  become_user: me
```

Comment: Start with reading the synchronize module's doc page. It's not a regular module, it works "the other way around", and it has limits regarding `sudo`.

Comment: Unless you showed an understanding of how it works, the question is unanswerable. One can only copy the examples from the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I went with this workaround

```
- local_action: command rsync -av /root/owned/dir/ {{ item }}:/root/owned/dir/
  with_items: "{{ groups['group'] }}"
  when: inventory_hostname != "{{item}}"
  become: no
```